# GCP Building VM with HDD by Using "gcloud compute instances import" Command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a 75 GB .OVA file in my bucket(250 GB as VM).

When I wanted to build this .OVA by using "gcloud compute instances import" command, I am getting **'SSD_TOTAL_GB'** exceeded error because of the quota(I am still in the testing phase, that is why I did not increased the quota).

However if I find a way to build this .OVA with any other storage type, I believe that the problem will be fixed.

I wanted to know that is there any way to build this .OVA file with standard persistent disk?

If there is no way to customize, do you have any suggestion for my issue?

There is some arguments that lets me customize my VM before building but there is no option for storage(such as --custom-cpu, --custom-memory, --custom-vm-type).

Thank you all.

Comment: The solution is to increase your persistent disk quota. There is no workaround to bypass that.